# Autofac Integration with self hosted Owin server returns 404 for all WebApi controllers with dependencies

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac, self-hosting

**Overview**

We have a solution that we are switching from ninject to autofac for DI.

We have a console application (.net 4.8) that starts two separate processes for testing locally. It starts an owin web application and a rules engine. Each process configures its own Autofac container (as it did with ninject).  The engine starts up great and starts all of it's separate periodic threads and background services using autofac.  We also have separate end to end tests that use the autofac container for some other testing.  The registrations work properly in those tests.

The Owin application starts up and has some mock controllers in the dev project and registers the controllers from from the production WebApi assembly.

**Details and Troubleshooting**

I have followed the autofac owin integration quick start as well as read and attempted solutions from other similar posts about autofac and 404 errors with WebApi.  Originally, I thought it was having an issue registering the controllers from the separate assembly, but I verified the controller was indeed registered in the autofac container as well as ensuring it was registered after calling `RegisterApiControllers()` to ensure it wasn't getting registered as a POCO object instead of an ApiController.

When I remove the autofac container entirely, I get the same behavior, so I don't think Owin is using autofac at all to provide the controllers when needed.

I have also attempted to create a brand new controller in the same assembly of the MockupUserscontroller and if I don't have any dependencies, it works.  As soon as I add a dependency, I get a 404 error. It appears that Owin is ignoring any controllers without default constructors, but I am unable to get it working.

*Again, all these tests worked properly with ninject as a container.  There were no changes to the controllers when the DI container was replaced.*

**Code**

Main top level service starting both the self hosted owin application as well as the engine.

```cs
    public static void Start()
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:8888";
        app = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress);
    }
```

Startup Class for Owin:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    // Top level error handling. Catches web api layer errors, etc.
    app.Use(
        async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.Error(ex);
#if DEBUG
                throw;
#endif
            }
        });
    var dependencyInjectionServiceFactory = new DependencyInjectionServiceFactory();
    var dependencyInjectionService = dependencyInjectionServiceFactory.CreateWebDevelopmentDependencyInjectionService();
    var containerBuilder = dependencyInjectionService.RegisterServices();
    containerBuilder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<MockAuthenticationFilter>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(t => t.FullName.Contains("Sepsis") && !t.FullName.Contains("DependencyInjection")).ToList();
    containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies.ToArray()).InstancePerRequest();
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();

    logger.Info(string.Join(",\n", assemblies.Select(a => a.FullName)));
    logger.Info($"\nIs {nameof(ProvidersController)} registered? " + container.IsRegistered<ProvidersController>());

    config.Filters.Add(container.Resolve<MockAuthenticationFilter>());
    var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    config.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container)
        .UseAutofacWebApi(config)
        .UseWebApi(config)
        .Use<RedirectMiddleware>()
        .UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    
    ConfigureTestData();
    logger.Info("Hey, I'm done and have not crashed.");
}
```

The mockup controller that works properly (DI not needed) and is located in the same assembly as the main service that launches both the engine and Owin

```cs
public class MockupUsersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MockupUserRepository mockupUserRepository = new MockupUserRepository();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("mockup_users/{org}")]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get(int org)
    {
        return mockupUserRepository.FindOrganization(org);
    }
}
```

The controller that resides in the production webapi assembly [not all methods are copied], but none of the endpoints work - all return 404 errors

```cs
public class ProvidersController : BaseControllerWithSessionContext
{
    private readonly IPatientService patientService;
    private readonly IRulesService rulesService;
    private readonly IProvidersService providersService;
    private readonly IContactService contactService;
    private readonly IKpiLoggingService kpiLoggingService;
    private readonly IPhiViewLogger phiViewLogger;
    private readonly IProviderImportService providerImportService;

    public ProvidersController(
        IPatientService patientService,
        IRulesService rulesService,
        IProvidersService providersService,
        IContactService contactService,
        IKpiLoggingService kpiLoggingService,
        IPhiViewLogger phiViewLogger,
        IServiceResultHandler serviceResultHandler,
        ISessionContextService sessionContextService,
        IProviderImportService providerImportService)
        : base(serviceResultHandler, sessionContextService)
    {
        this.rulesService = rulesService;
        this.patientService = patientService;
        this.providersService = providersService;
        this.contactService = contactService;
        this.kpiLoggingService = kpiLoggingService;
        this.phiViewLogger = phiViewLogger;
        this.providerImportService = providerImportService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all providers for organization
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("sites/{SiteId}/providers")]
    [AuthorizeRoles(Roles.Administrator, Roles.User)]
    public IEnumerable<FrontendProvider> GetAll([FromUri] SiteRequest request)
    {
        return providersService.All(request.SiteId);
    }
}
```

**Any help is appreciated.  I am running out of ideas to try.**

Comment: Why are you setting UseAutofacMiddleware with a child scope? [The working example doesn't do that.](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/6788fcf77ed7ac21f07959ed54f6718096f85b13/src/WebApiExample.OwinSelfHost/Startup.cs#L44) Also, this is clearly [not a minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - try one controller, one action, one dependency instead of all of this. No one is going to peel through this amount of code. Minimal repro also helps you locate the trouble, it's not just for us.

Comment: Thanks @TravisIllig - I am working on a minimal while upgrading the solution.  I will post here when I have the minimal solution.  I will also try removing the scope.  I hadn't really noticed that.

I have tried just getting a basic controller to work and Owin picks it up, but it is not resolving from autofac - as soon as I add a dependency, I get a 404 - not autofac unable to resolve errors.

Comment: @TravisIllig - I have removed the scope and still have the same result :( - hoping it was something that dumb. Oh well.  Working on an upgraded solution.